# got strange error when activating "Publish" feature on site collection : DAV:href for sts4s://myCompanyName.company.nl/siteurl=opleiding/wei/siteid

Tags: uls

I try to activate the "Publish Infrastructure" feature on a site collection. But I got a error with a correlation guid. In the uls viewer I see this error:

> DAV:href for
>   sts4s://myCompanyName.company.nl/siteurl=opleiding/wei/siteid={67b77846-8434-4e0b-b955-243438e5af84}/weburl=/webid={616ff240-bbf9-4cbf-807a-a5af40f7e38c}/listid={652f704f-fcbb-4814-9e8d-b6c84d638c72} is empty  [sts3filt.cxx:573] 
>   d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3filt.cxx

Anybody knows what is wrong?

Comment: I also got this error and removed the 3 columns, but didnt fixed my problem to activate the feature: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2610f129-8e00-4e31-987b-b62efc228c3f/error-when-activating-the-sharepoint-server-publishing-infrastructure-feature?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: i dont suppose you upgraded by any chance?